# How can i stop Timeshift from changing my second ssd mount point

Tags: mount, hard-drive, backup, ssd, timeshift

[image]I have two SSD's in my laptop. One SSD is where my system lies, and the other is used for data/media storage. I have set up Timeshift to make three daily backups, and to save them on the ssd for media/data storage.

However, this has the unintended side-effect of every so often (probably when the backups are made) unmounting the disk from /media/[username]/[partition_name]
file:///media/munene/Munene files

to /run/timeshift/backup. It becomes unavailable in the file explorer, and I have to open the Disks utility, unmount and remount it in order to access the files on it again.

/media and /root has always been excluded from the backup. I stopped taking backups because if timeshifts runs the second ssd disappears from nautilus. apparently these locations can't be mounted more than once at different places in the filesystem

Comment: TimeShift will mount the storage location to /run/timeshift/backup whenever it runs. It doesn’t unmount when it’s finished. That shouldn’t be a problem because the same thing can be mounted more than once at different places in the filesystem. Does the data storage get unmounted every time TimeShift is run? I suggest you explicitly exclude /media from the backup. My guess is TimeShift recognises that without unmounting the data storage you would be asking it to make a backup of the backup location.

Comment: /media and /root has always been excluded from the backup. I stopped taking backups because if timeshifts runs the second ssd disappears from nautilus. apparently these locations can't be mounted more than once at different places in the filesystem

Comment: According to the mount manual page “Since Linux 2.4 a single filesystem can be mounted at multiple mount points, and multiple mounts can be stacked on the same mount point.” How do you mount your second drive? Is it automatically mounted at boot or do you use the disks utility each time?

Comment: I’ve set your scenario up in a virtual machine. My second disk was mounted at /media/John/. When TimeShift did its thing the second disk was mounted at /run/timeshift/backup. The /media mount remained during and after the TimeShift snapshot. Your issue may be elsewhere